# Capistrano: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm really new to Capistrano and am having a tough time getting it setup.  I'm using a Windows local machine, Linux server and BitBucket for my git repo.  When I run `cap deploy` I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railsless-deploy-1.1.2/lib/railsless-deploy.rb:98:in ``': No such file or directory - git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:je3415/captest.git HEAD
 (Errno::ENOENT)
```

When I SSH into the server I'm able to run `git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:je3415/captest.git HEAD` without any problem.  I also tried creating a public key with and without a passphrase.  That made no difference as well.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.  Thanks.

**Edit:**
Here is the contents of my capfile:

```
require 'railsless-deploy'
load 'config/deploy'
```

And the beginning of my deploy.rb file looks like this:

```
set :stages, %w(production staging)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, "captest" # TODO
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:je3415/captest.git" # TODO
set :scm, :git
set :use_sudo, false

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :copy_exclude, [".git", ".DS_Store", ".gitignore", ".gitmodules"]
set :git_enable_submodules, 1
set :wp_multisite, 0 # TODO Set to 1 if multisite
```

Comment: posting your capfile would help

Comment: Thanks @beefjerky.  I've updated the question with my capfile as well as the beginning of my deploy.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding the location of my Git binaries to the Windows PATH environment variable.  Thanks to @maksim for posting the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8978686/868082.